# Display unicode in tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux, unicode, urxvt

This is urxvt without tmux

[image: no tmux]

This is urxvt with tmux and utf8 not enabled in the config

[image: tmux with utf8 enabled]

This is urxvt with tmux and utf8 enabled in the config

[image: tmux with utf8 not enabled]

How can I make tmux act consistent with the initial result?

Comment: Where can I get that `glyphs` application to test the results?

Comment: The glyphs script is from this: https://github.com/lucy/tewi-font/blob/master/glyphs

I've actually stopped having this problem a long time ago, with no action on my part. I installed Windows 7 since posting as well.

Answer (score 6):

Would you please try the following and see if it helps?

- rename .tmux.conf to something else
- set LANG="en_US.UTF-8"

Clarification:

I have seen the existence of ~/.tmux.conf may cause problem so just for testing I suggested to rename the file.  And forcing  LANG=en_US.UTF-8 is another measure to ensure the correct locale to be used (since Hal didn't supply his LANG setting(s))

Comment: Can you make your instructions a little more explicit?  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 : I'm not meaning to endorse this, but just to elaborate on the steps.  Get to a command line (Bourne shell or mostly-compatible, like bash, ought to work fine; I expect urxvt ought to work fine).  Type these lines into the command prompt: First line: `mv ~/.tmux.conf ~/tmux.conf.bak` Second line: `set LANG="en_US.UTF-8"` ; Third line: `tmux` ; Fourth line: `glyphs`